# Regarding Places Library for Google Maps API Quota limits

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Quick question, just to clarify the wording and meaning (because it's changed a couple of times for Map loading...)

There are the two following statements in the Places API FAQs:

> The Google Places API has the following query limits:
>
> Users with an API key are allowed 1 000 requests per 24 hour period.
>   Users who have verified their identity through the APIs console are
>   allowed 100 000 requests per 24 hour period. A credit card is required
>   for verification, by enabling billing in the console. We ask for your
>   credit card purely to validate your identity. Your card will not be
>   charged for use of the Places API. While the lower limit is sufficient
>   for development and testing, we recommend enabling the higher limit
>   before launching your application. It is possible to request an
>   additional quota. If granted, the additional quota is free of charge.
>   If, at some stage in the future, an option becomes available to pay
>   for an additional quota, that quota will be over and above the
>   existing free quota, and you will need to sign up for it explicitly.
>
> Note that some services may have a multiplier:
>
> The Text Search service is subject to a 10-times multiplier. That is,
>   each Text Search request that you make will count as 10 requests
>   against your quota. The Radar Search Service is subject to a 5-times
>   multiplier. That is, each Radar Search request that you make will
>   count as 5 requests against your quota. If you've purchased the Google
>   Places API as part of your Maps API for Business contract, the
>   multiplier may be different. Please refer to the Google Maps API for
>   Business documentation for details.

This implies that use of the Google Places API is restricted to 100,000 queries per day, or 10,000 if you're doing a Text Search.

However, on the Uplift page, it says the following:

> If you are developing a web based application that only needs to
>   search for places, and is not submitting new places or Place Bumps,
>   you should use the Places library of the Maps API rather than using
>   the Places API web service. The Places library assigns a quota to each
>   end user rather than to each key. This means that your available quota
>   increases with your user base rather than being capped at a fixed
>   amount.

I am using the Places API in the following way:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&libraries=places
...
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(request, callback);
```

And also for some details searching and photo searching.

Therefore my question is; ***Given my usage of the Places API, am I subject to the 100,000 queries limit on my app, or am I essentially uncapped at an app level, as my quota is per end-user?*** (i.e. per unique IP?  if I had 10,000 users I have an effective quota for my entire user base of 100,000*10,000?)

EDIT:

For clarity: if I throw my API key into `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=XXXX`, it will increment my Places quota count on the Google API console, however if I run queries through my JS app, I see no quota use change.  I want to make sure that i'm not suddenly going to be hit with a massive quota result.

Comment: We are not google, we can't give you a guarantee for anything. But your assumption is correct, currently you(your google-account) will not hit the limit when you use the JS-API.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't looking for an iron-clad guarantee, more that my interpretation of the rules is correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of the JavaScript API services, like those provided by the Places library, have quota assigned to each end-user.  It's a very similar setup as objects like the `google.maps.Geocoder`, which has been discussed in a bit more detail in this [Geocoding Strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) article.

Answer (score 1):

You may apply for an uplift to the quota so that the restriction is taken away and you have unlimited access:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/18pkOdu0uofeI8tbQoReDVfkbOIAscLvjiKc9ZP06hEM/viewform

This form is applicable to Android, IOS and Web.