# JavaScript Maps API v3 quotas, how do they work?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to access all sorts of map data through Google Maps and I'm trying to figure out how the quota's and installation works.

From the reading I've done, it seems that with **[JavaScript Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)** (which allows for 25,000 requests per day) installed, I'll have access to the following 'sub API's' if you will.

- **[Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding/)** | 2,500 requests per day
- **[Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)** | 100 requests per day
- **[Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)** | 2,500 requests per day
- **[Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)** | 1,000 requests per day

It looks like [each will require an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem) (including JavaScript Maps API v3), and each has it's own quota limit.  It's laid out in a confusing way though. It seems that they can be access using the JavaScript Maps API v3 which has a 25,000 map load limit, or individually loaded.

If they are individually loaded, is that when the separate quota kicks in?

**Note:**  I also found [this page](https://developers.google.com/places/usage) which states that

> Applications that submit requests with an API key are allowed 1,000
>   requests per 24 hour period.

This throws another wrench into the whole thing and I'm really confused with all of this documentation.  The bottom line is that I will need access to the above 5 bolded items.  Is it as simple as just using **JavaScript Maps API v3** to access the other 4, and all requests made will fall into the 25,000 request quota?

Any Google Map gurus out there?

Answer (score 0):

The APIs all have their own keys, which you activate via the API console, but are all accessed (in the case of a JS Maps application) through your single Maps API key.

The main thing that they don't make particularly obvious, is that for Javascript applications, the quota is per-client, so your limit essentially scales to your user-base.

I asked a similar question here, and the response I got (as well as my own research and experimentation) backs that up:

[Regarding Places Library for Google Maps API Quota limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746264/regarding-places-library-for-google-maps-api-quota-limits)

If you want to test this, create a dummy JS app which queries one of the libaries a couple of times, and check the quota on your API console - it should be zero.  However, if you `curl` the same query from the command line, it will increase the quota.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This does clarify things a bit in terms of the keys.  I'll need to activate all through API console, but use one in the application (Maps API key).  Am I correct in thinking that loading up JavaScript Maps API v3 will give me access to all of the libraries I've mentioned?

Comment: @Tony M: don't mix up the API's . When you only use the Maps-Javascript-API (with a key), the only API you'll have to activate is **Google Maps JavaScript API v3** . The only limit for you in this case is for Maps-load( 25.000/day) . Any limits for the services requested via the maps-Javascript-API belong to the user (which requests the page with the map in his browser). The other API's must be activated when you request them via a serverside application(and all the limits for these API's will apply to your account)

Comment: @Dr.Molle: Quite right, I should have made my answer clearer.  Each API has it's own key, but all can be accessed specifically via the Javascript API without enabling each API separately.  Therefore, when you want to use a particular library in a client-side application, you would do something like `var geocoder = new Google.Maps.Geocoder();`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to access these APIs:

1. As a JavaScript API v3 library/service
2. As [RESTful HTTP Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/)

For the JavaScript API, only map loads are counted and you could in theory perform as many services calls as you want. However, you will run into OVER_QUERY_LIMIT responses if you just hammer the service with requests. ([see for example this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014074/google-maps-api-over-query-limit-per-second-limit))

For the RESTful web services, the limits you already found apply.