# Does the google maps API v3 have a query limit for individual IPs as well as a total site daily limit?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956479/javascript-maps-api-v3-quotas-how-do-they-work?rq=1) and some others that state that the usage limit is 25,000 client side requests per day and that there is a query limit which I haven't found a figure for.

Is there also a limit for the requests that a single user could make? Could a single IP rather than many site users make 25000 requests in a 24 hour period?

Comment: What is a *single user*?  Google maps (non-enterprise) is stateless so I don't understand the question.

Comment: By single user I mean one browser session/IP address. I assumed that google has some kind of rate limiting for that as well as the total daily limit.

Comment: What you described google refers to as a `client side request`.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not with Google Maps API. Google MAP Api is flexible with the usage. They don't shut down API if your usage goes beyond 25000 in a day. They check it for period of 90 days.

If usage is still higher then you need to buy paid service.

For reference please check this link below

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Regards
Atul

Comment: My question isn't about whether or not they shut it down, it's whether there is a limit to the number of client side requests from a single IP using a single API key.

Comment: Yes they have limit usages, its near about 25000 requests per day from single ip address and API key