# How do the limits work for the Google Javascript Places Library?

Tags: meteor, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on building my first web/mobile app with Meteor, using Javascript for both the client and server.

Essentially, the app will allow users to rate restaurants based on a variety of factors, such as how loud it is or how nice it smells. The averages of each of these attributes would then be stored in my database along with the Google ID of the associated restaurant. Other users can then search for places near them and sort the results based on any of the rated attributes.

So if a user requests a list of places and a request is made to the Google places library API, and then those places are matched against data in my database, how are the limits applied? Since the server is also running with Javascript, can I call the API with the server? And if I do, is the API able to distinguish between different users and apply the individual limits? Or if it's all coming from a single server will it give me a total limit equivalent to a single user?

Thanks for any help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps JavaScript Places Library does not have a documented limit. However, if you perform request that have gone over its request quota, you will get `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`. So maybe the [Javascript API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) can help you to know more about limits by using this API.

Check also this related [SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746264/regarding-places-library-for-google-maps-api-quota-limits).